# React router history.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have two problems. I've read some SO posts and browsed through various docs, but I run into different explanations.

This is what I've got:

```
var Router = window.ReactRouter.Router;
var useRouterHistory = window.ReactRouter.useRouterHistory;
var Route = window.ReactRouter.Route;
var Link = window.ReactRouter.Link;
const createHistory = window.History.createHistory;
const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({ queryKey: false });

var MyTable = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    ...
    history.push({
      pathname: window.location.href.split('?')[0],
      search: querystring,
      state: { 'data': initial_data }
    });
    ...
    },
    ...
});

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={appHistory}>
    <Route path={window.page_url} component={MyTable}>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('my-table-wrapper'));
```

Problem number 1 is: history.push is not a function.

Problem number 2 is: if I use, for example, window.history.pushState, I do get nice URLs that change on browser's back and forward buttons and I saw that I can perform actions onpopstate. What is the equivalent of that for the history that I'm trying to use above?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should call `push` on `appHistory`, not `history`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - I misunderstood the "history={appHistory}" part in the Router - I thought that the appHistory will be called history inside the components.